# Concatenar un char a char*

Tags: array, c, string

necesito concatenar una letra de un char a un char*. A continuación dos ejemplos:

```
token[i] = "o";  //token[i] = "o"
char* sub;       //sub = "perr"
---------------------------------------
token[i] = "g";  //token[i] = "g"
char* sub;       //sub = ""
```

El resultado que quiero es:

```
char* sub;       //sub = perro
---------------------------------------
char* sub;       //sub = g
```

Para lograr esto, tengo esta función, pero no me lleva a ningún resultado:

```
void concatenar(char c, char *cadena){
    char cadenaTemporal[2];
    cadenaTemporal[0] = c;
    cadenaTemporal[1] = '\0';
    strcat(cadena, cadenaTemporal);
}
```

La idea es lograr el objetivo ejecutando la función de la siguiente manera:

```
concatenar(token[i],sub);
```

El programa finaliza su ejecución de forma anticipada al llegar al strcat. No se cual es el error. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Probandolo de la siguiente manera: `char texto[10] = "Perr"; concatenar('o', texto); printf("%s", texto);` la funcion parece funcionar perfectamente. Asi que el problema no se encuentra en el codigo que nos compartes. Posiblemente le estes dando un buffer muy pequeño. Puedes compartir mas codigo? Asegurate de que lo que compartas sea [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). De otro modo no te podremos ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

Para empezar debes tener claros los conceptos con los que pretendes trabajar.

No existe ningún concepto parecido a "*una letra de un char*". Una variable de tipo `char` es conceptualmente un carácter (que en algunos casos puede ser una letra). Lo que pretendes es:

> Necesito concatenar una letra en un texto.

---

Ahora aclaremos el concepto de "*texto*" en [c](/questions/tagged/c): En el lenguaje no existe un dato que sea texto, pero sí que existen formaciones<sup>1</sup> de caracteres (habitualmente `char`) que suelen recibir el nombre de *string*. Los *string* son formaciones y las formaciones se suelen gestionar medante punteros al tipo contenido en la formación:

```
char x[] = "hola"; // x es una formación de 5 caracteres: 'h', 'o', 'l', 'a', '\0'
```

Las formaciones necesitan un espacio en el que contener todos sus elementos y este espacio está prefijado en tiempo de compilación (como el ejemplo de `char x[]`) o en tiempo de ejecución. El problema de este espacio es que al estar prefijado no puede ampliarse o recortarse así que sólo existen dos opciones:

1. El *string* resultante de la concatenación se aloja en un espacio de memoria nuevo dejando el *string* original inalterado.
2. Se realoja el espacio del *string* original a uno con más espacio y se escribe en la nueva memoria el carácter a concatenar.

Voy a mostrar un ejemplo del segundo caso:

```
char buffer[1000] = "";
printf("Escribe una palabra: ");
scanf("%s", buffer);

int size = strlen(buffer);
char *palabra = (char *)malloc(size + 1); // Creamos un arreglo para la palabra
strcpy(palabra, buffer);                  // Copiamos en el nuevo arreglo la palabra

printf("Antes de concatenar: %s", palabra);

char letra;
printf("Escribe una letra: ");
scanf("%c", &letra);
printf("Concatenar letra %c en posición %d", letra, size);

palabra = (char *)realloc(palabra, size + 2); // Realojamos la memoria del arreglo
palabra[size] = letra;                        // Añadimos al final la nueva letra

printf("Despues de concatenar: %s", palabra);
free(palabra); // Liberamos memoria
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Un par de notas sobre el codigo. Cuando lees la palabra haria falta que añadieras un `%*c` luego del `%s`. De otro modo cuando leas la letra mas adelante leera el salto de linea que quedo en el buffer. Y cuando concatenas la letra omites el `\0` al final de la cadena.